# Fill an array from For loops to create all the possibilities from 4 letters

Tags: java, c++, arrays, for-loop

I'm trying ton convert the following code from c++ to java and as I'm a beginner student in Java I have  errors when tryin to assign the char to **tabtemp**. I didnt found examples with multiple For loops

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    for (char a = 97; a <= 100; a++)
        for (char b = 97; b <= 100; b++)
            for (char c = 97; c <= 100; c++)
               for (char d = 97; d <= 100; d++)
               {
                   string tabtemp = { a,b,c,d };
                   {
                       cout << tabtemp << endl;
                   }
               }

    return 0;
}
```

1st try in java

```
public class Alpha {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (char a = 97; a <= 100; a++) {
            for (char b = 97; b <= 100; b++)
                for (char c = 97; c <= 100; c++)
                    for (char d = 97; d <= 100; d++);

            char[] tabtemp = {a,b,c,d};
            System.out.println(tabtemp);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Remove ; after the last for statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do something like this in Java:

```
char[] tabtemp = null;
        for (char a = 97; a <= 100; a++) {
            for (char b = 97; b <= 100; b++) {
                for (char c = 97; c <= 100; c++) {
                    for (char d = 97; d <= 100; d++) {
                        tabtemp = new char[]{a, b, c, d};
                    }
                }
            }

            System.out.println(tabtemp);
        }
```

Comment: Thousand thanks!